# Duplicate records are displayed while trying to bind different data to the same div using knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a div which displays 10 records a time.When user clicks on next link, the next 10 records will be loaded from server. But after binding, the newly added records are shown multiple times. Kindly help me to know where I am going wrong.

```
     function displayLastMonthVolume() {            

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "DashBoard.aspx/GetLastMonthVolume",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {                   
                        if (response != undefined && response != '') {    
                            var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
                            var totalAmt = 0;
                            for (var p = 0; p < data.length; p++) {
                                totalAmt += data[p].Amount;
                            }
                            data.TotalAmt = totalAmt;
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('lastmonth_Trans'));    
                            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(data, document.getElementById('lastmonth_Trans'));    
                        }                        
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });    
                return true;
            }
```

UI :

```
     <div class="lastmonthdialogpopup" title="Transaction made over the last days">
<table id="lastmonth_Trans" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="device_tbl" >
  <thead><tr><th valign="middle" align="center">Date</th>
  <th valign="middle" align="left">Merchant Name</th>
  <th valign="middle" align="center"> Amount  </th>
  <th valign="middle" align="left"> Pty_ID </th> </tr></thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root">
  <tr><td valign="middle" align="left" data-bind="text: Date"> </td>
   <td valign="middle" align="left" data-bind="text: Name"> </td>
  <td valign="middle" align="right" data-bind="text: Amount.toFixed(2)">
   </td>
  <td valign="middle" align="left" data-bind="text: PtyId"> </td>
  <td valign="middle" align="left" data-bind="text: ID"> </td> </tr>
  </tbody><tfoot><tr><td><b>Total</b></td> <td></td>
  <td valign="middle" align="right" data-bind="text: TotalAmt.toFixed(2)">/td>
 <td></td> </tr> </tfoot></table>
 <a id="expandLink" onclick="displayLastMonthVolume()" style="cursor: pointer; color: #ff8c00;">Next</a> </div>
```

Comment: Why are you rebinding? You should only bind once and then add the new records to the end of the observable array, this will make them render as you want

Comment: @Luis: I am quite new to knockout. Could you please tell, how to add new records to observable array by removing the previous records and also I have to bind the div only when user selected the div

Comment: Do you want to append the records or just replace them?

Comment: I need to replace them

Comment: I need to go now I will jump in later on and if none answered I will leave a sample for you

Comment: Have a look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/GF3kh/119/ , the only difference is that the ajax call will retrieve different json objects, once you load them in the observable array they will be replaced by the new values

Comment: actually i have changed the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/GF3kh/161/ click the button mutliple times and see the date changing

Comment: I will leave it as an answer so you can accept it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to bind once and then replace the new data in the observable array, the 2 way data-binding will replace all the rendered items in the foreach binding with the new ones.

Here is a sample that exemplifies this for you:

```
var viewModel = {
    // Data
    entries: ko.observableArray(),
    numberOfRecords: ko.observable(),
    dataTimeOfLastCall: ko.observable(),
    retrieveLogs: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON([
                    { Id: 1, Message: 'message one', Machine: 'machine one', UserId: 'user 1', EntryDate: new Date() },
                    { Id: 2, Message: 'message two', Machine: 'machine two', UserId: 'user 2', EntryDate: new Date() },
                ]),
                delay: 1
            },
            context: this,
            success: function(data) {
                this.entries($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return new logEntry(item);
                }));
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
};

function logEntry(item) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(item.Id);
    this.Message = ko.observable(item.Message);
    this.Machine = ko.observable(item.Machine);
    this.UserName = ko.observable(item.UserId);
    this.EntryDate = ko.
    observable(item.EntryDate);

    return this;
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Notice that every time you click the button the records in the foreach are replaced (check the date changing)

http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/GF3kh/161/

Comment: I have another problem. I have a page with three div's. When user clicks on div the respective div should be displayed with data. The binding of data/code with ajax call is written in one page. where Should I place the ko.applybindings() in this case. Currently, the applybindings is written on the ajax call success event. Now too, we have multiple bindings